# Linux Kernel 5.6.2 - Can't Find Block Device to Mount Root Filesystem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, mount

I work in a very heavily regulated industry. I've been tasked with creating a secure boot chain. That is, from boot, it needs to boot into a minimal Linux Kernel who's initramfs has a Python init script and additional programming to do integrity checks. Once/if the integrity checks are successful, the user can then complete the boot.

The init script needs to be able to find the hard drive and pass it to the integrity checker. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to correctly mount the root filesystem.

I'm very new to Linux, so I'm trying to piece things together as I go along. From what I've gathered:

The initramfs is a temporary file system to allow the mounting of the true root filesystem (usually `/dev/sda1`, I believe). However, there are no sd* files/nodes when I `ls /dev` in the initramfs. I've tried implementing some Python code that creates the `sda` and `sda1` nodes and then creates a filesystem via `mkfs` on `sda1`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
Hello! This is python
0 // result of mknod /dev/sda b 8 0
0 // result of mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 1
1 mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Could not open /dev/sda1: No such device or address
1 df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
Mounting proc...
mount /proc
0 // result of mount /proc

0 Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on // result of df
rootfs            202828 202828         0 100% /
end of df
0 # Begin /etc/fstab // result of cat /etc/fstab

# file system  mount-point  type   options          dump  fsck
#                                                         order

/dev/sda      /            ext4 defaults         1     1
proc           /proc        proc   defaults         0     0
sysfs          /sys         sysfs  defaults         0     0
devpts         /dev/pts     devpts gid=4,mode=620   0     0
shm            /dev/shm     tmpfs  defaults         0     0
# End /etc/fstab
end of fstab
0 major minor  #blocks  name // result of cat /proc/partitions

  11        0    1048575 sr0
end of /proc/partitions
2 device     fs_type label    mount point    UUID // result of blkid -o list

end of blkid
Checking...
0 
0 


0 rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,size=202828k,nr_inodes=50707) // result of mount 
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
Can't find platform/dev/sda // result of a function to find the necessary partition on disk 
Halted.
```

Comment: "_I've been tasked with creating a secure boot chain_" and "_I'm very new to Linux_" seem to be a strange combination

Comment: @roaima, yeah, it's out of necessity and a lack of more experienced engineers. Admittedly, I don't think I'm doing too bad, but this is definitely above my pay-grade.

Comment: It almost sounds like you should use dm-verity instead of rolling your own integrity checker... (It's the same tool that powers Android's verified boot.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have support for sda enabled in your minimal kernel, or you are loading the necessary kernel modules to enable the serial ATA support *AND* the filesystem on it (ext4).